# Div grow out of bounds if content is too much

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a parent element which has a `max-width` but inside I have a table that I want to expand past that `max-width`, but only if it's necessary because of the content on the table.

Here's a fiddle so you can see: https://jsfiddle.net/z6nbc75g/

Try clicking the "add columns" button a few times to see how when you add too many, they start getting compressed instead of making the table wider.

Here's the code:

```css
.parent {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 20rem;
}

.table .row {
  display: flex;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  padding: 4px;
}

.table .col {
  border: 1px solid red;
  padding: 2px;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="table">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col">lorem ipsum</div>
      <div class="col">lorem ipsum</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col">lorem ipsum</div>
      <div class="col">lorem ipsum</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col">lorem ipsum</div>
      <div class="col">lorem ipsum</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col">lorem ipsum</div>
      <div class="col">lorem ipsum</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @Ingus nope, my case is actually the opposite and totally different

Comment: Is it an option for you to set a `  min-width` on `.table .col`?

Comment: What’s the desired outcome? Horizontal scroll in parent? Columns visible outside parent?

Comment: Add `flex-shrink: 0;` to your `.table .col{}` rule and it won't shrink

Comment: And do note, for the `.parent` to grow along with the content it needs to be displayed `inline-flex/block`.

Comment: And FYI, if an element is suppose to expand beyond a given width, do not use `max-width`, instead use `min-width`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `min-width: max-content`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/width#max-content

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/r84q7nvj/

Comment: This works but the browser support is terrible :/

Comment: @nick I see. I have added an alternative answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can make change in the style of row. Add flex-wrap property.

```
.table .row {
  display: flex;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  padding: 4px;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For what you're looking for, a way to handle this would be to make your `.parent` element as an `inline-block` (so it only occupies the width of the child elements), then prevent wrapping on the columns (assuming you want all of your content within a column to be on the same line - if you don't, the table will still expand until it reaches the width of the page, then cause the text to wrap within the columns).

Snippet below - I've added in the button from your jsfiddle so you can test this out :)

```js
document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', () => {
 let rows = document.querySelectorAll('.row');
  
  rows.forEach(row => {
   let col = document.createElement('div');
    col.classList.add('col');
    col.textContent = 'lorem ipsum';
    
    row.appendChild(col);
  });
});
```

```css
.parent {
  display:inline-block;
}

.table .row {
  display: flex;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  padding: 4px;
}

.table .col {
  border: 1px solid red;
  padding: 2px;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="table">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col">lorem ipsum</div>
      <div class="col">lorem ipsum</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col">lorem ipsum</div>
      <div class="col">lorem ipsum</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col">lorem ipsum</div>
      <div class="col">lorem ipsum</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col">lorem ipsum</div>
      <div class="col">lorem ipsum</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<button>Add columns</button>
```

Comment: It works but the row width doesn't change, it just overflows

Comment: Hi @nick, I've pulled out the `white-space:nowrap` - is that more what you're looking for?

Answer (score 0):

You could also solve this using `display: inline-flex` on the parent together with `min-width: 200px` and `flex-basis` on its children: https://jsfiddle.net/cnxgruzt/